# brightness settings not ajustable

Tags: 13.04, brightness, acer, backlight, aspire

I gave it a search and found this for version 11.04 on an acer aspire;

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Edit two lines to read as follows:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux

sudo update-grub
```

I am confident I executed it correctly but it had no effect. However I have no experience with Ubuntu and this is the first thing I’ve tried to fix before doing anything else. So please keep replies as descriptive as possible. Am running an Acer aspire V3-###G(not sure of numbers 871 maybe??) with Ubuntu 13.04.

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 13.04 I faced the same problem.

Please use this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor“
```

It works for my Acer Aspire.

I have also updated:
http://nikunjlahoti.com/2012/04/29/ubuntu-12-04-fix-fn-brightness-keys/

Answer (score 0):

maybe u can use this i have used this after i failed trying your process .....

1:open the terminal and then type

sudo gedit /etc/rc.local

2:
Add this before the last line “exit 0″:

echo 4 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness

3: reboot.

NOTE-if this doesn't work goto ubuntu software centre and install leafpad then type 'leafpad' wthiout quotes in place of gedit and try the above process....