# Dell display problem Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, dell, brightness

Since I upgrade from ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04 I can't change the brightness of the display, it remain in the darkest possible mode. I have a Dell 3721 laptop. Any advice?

```
@Dell:~$ lspci -nn | grep VGA 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
```

If I use this, I can change the brigntess, but its so uncomfortable, why I cant use the hotkeys or ubuntu system controll anymore?

```
echo 3500 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

Comment: Look at: http://askubuntu.com/questions/293926/brightness-settings-not-ajustable

Answer (score 0):

xbacklight is a command line utility for adjusting brightness and may help you.
Install it using the command:

> sudo apt-get install xbacklight

and adjust your brightness to using below command:

> xbacklight -set percentage brightness
>
> example(for 50% brightness): xbacklight -set 50